# Using T-SQL DATEFROMPARTS to return NULL instead of throw error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Often I've received dates in the form of some combination of integers or a single 8 digit integer. To convert them to a usable date I tried the DATEFROMPARTS function but when the dates were nonsensical it threw an error when a NULL would be preferred.

I hoped to find a function with behavior that similar to TRY_PARSE that takes integers and returns NULL for invalid dates rather than an error but without the need for string casting as I'd like to use it in a PERSISTED calculated field. In the end, I just decided to test the integers before converting like so.

```
CASE WHEN @year BETWEEN 1 AND 9999 AND (@month BETWEEN 1 AND 12 AND @day BETWEEN 1 AND 28
       OR @month IN(1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12) AND @day BETWEEN 1 AND 31
       OR @month IN(4, 6, 9, 11) AND @day BETWEEN 1 AND 30
       OR @month = 2 AND @day BETWEEN 1 and CASE WHEN NOT @year % 4 = 0 THEN 28 WHEN NOT @year % 100 = 0 THEN 29 WHEN NOT @year % 400 = 0 THEN 28 ELSE 29 END)
     THEN DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, @day) END
```

This gives a date or a NULL for all 10 million relevant integer inputs (year from 0 to 9999, month from 0 to 99 and day from 0 to 99) I assume the results are correct but I haven't finished testing. Is there a better way to safely convert integer inputs to dates for a persisted calculated field (hence no string conversion allowed) that won't throw an error that I didn't find?

Comment: You need to fix your data types homie...

Comment: While I must not know you like Zane does, I would consider it better practice to store Date, DateTime, or DateTime2.  Calculated fields for year, month, and day are trivial, you'll make better use of indexes, and you wont be carrying around bad data.  Simply put, you've chosen to deal with bad data on the back end instead of stopping bad data on the front end.

Comment: Perhaps you should have it the other way around. A `DATE` column and 3 persisted calculated columns of `year`, `month`, `day` (as @jtimperley pointed, 6 seconds faster).

Comment: @jtimperley, if I had the date, I wouldn't need to calculate year, month and day for any purpose. Those are simply forced on me and many of them are nonsensical as dates. I need from that is a date and a means to reliably convert and persist valid dates while ignoring invalid dates. The question is if there's another more reliable method than testing the date with the algorithm above?

Comment: @ypercube, if I could have it the other way around that'd be nice. I have no use for the year, month and day as integers by themselves other than to get a date to store in a date field without errors being thrown for invalid dates.

Comment: I am simply suggesting you are trying to fix the wrong side of your problem.  A one-time fix for the inputs and storage will carry many benefits through your system.  To paraphrase Eric Evans, you must pay your Technical debt or to avoid bankruptcy.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion @jtimperley and while it may be best practice, that side of isn't my problem to solve and is out of my control. That of course doesn't change that I have to consume it.

Comment: `Is there a better way to safely convert integer inputs to dates for a persisted calculated field (hence no string conversion allowed)...` – what is the issue here? Why would you not want string conversion?

Comment: @AndriyM, a string conversion with TRY_PARSE wouldn't persist because it's non-deterministic.

Comment: Regarding your last comment to a now deleted answer, I'm not sure that with that method you need the additional check I suggested. But in any event, could you post your final solution as an answer (if that was indeed the solution you decided to go with)?

Comment: @AndriyM, when I have a single integer to represent a date it doesn't need to check but when I have 3 integers, I still need some checking with this phrase that you folks helped me to arrive at

`CASE WHEN [year] BETWEEN 1 AND 9999 AND [month] BETWEEN 1 AND 12 AND [day] BETWEEN 1 AND 31 THEN TRY_CONVERT(date, TRY_CONVERT(varchar, [year] * 10000 + [month] * 100 + [day], 112), 112) END`

It seems `TRY_CONVERT` with style 112 **is deterministic** whereas the now deleted answer was **not deterministic**.

Comment: All right, thanks. My question was about the check, which I thought you didn't need (and I've now verified that you actually don't). You also don't need the 112 on the inner TRY_CONVERT. Other than that, your solution seems really good and I honestly believe you should post it as an *answer*.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understood you right, but it might help:

```
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(100)= '1993';
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(100)= '12';
DECLARE @day VARCHAR(100)= '01';


SELECT CASE 
WHEN  ISNUMERIC(@year) = 0 OR  ISNUMERIC(@month) = 0 OR  ISNUMERIC(@day) = 0 THEN NULL
WHEN @year BETWEEN 1 AND 9999 AND (@month BETWEEN 1 AND 12 AND @day BETWEEN 1 AND 28
       OR @month IN(1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12) AND @day BETWEEN 1 AND 31
       OR @month IN(4, 6, 9, 11) AND @day BETWEEN 1 AND 30
       OR @month = 2 AND @day BETWEEN 1 and CASE WHEN NOT @year % 4 = 0 THEN 28 WHEN NOT @year % 100 = 0 THEN 29 WHEN NOT @year % 400 = 0 THEN 28 ELSE 29 END)
     THEN DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, @day) END;
```

OUTPUT:

> 1993-12-01

```
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(100)= '1993';
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(100)= 'Jan';
DECLARE @day VARCHAR(100)= '01';


SELECT CASE 
WHEN  ISNUMERIC(@year) = 0 OR  ISNUMERIC(@month) = 0 OR  ISNUMERIC(@day) = 0 THEN NULL
WHEN @year BETWEEN 1 AND 9999 AND (@month BETWEEN 1 AND 12 AND @day BETWEEN 1 AND 28
       OR @month IN(1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12) AND @day BETWEEN 1 AND 31
       OR @month IN(4, 6, 9, 11) AND @day BETWEEN 1 AND 30
       OR @month = 2 AND @day BETWEEN 1 and CASE WHEN NOT @year % 4 = 0 THEN 28 WHEN NOT @year % 100 = 0 THEN 29 WHEN NOT @year % 400 = 0 THEN 28 ELSE 29 END)
     THEN DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, @day) END;
```

OUTPUT:

> NULL

Comment: The function works as the inputs are integers. My question is if there's another way to reliably and safely produce a date from integers for a persisted calculated field. There can't be string types as the statement must be usable in a persisted calculated field.